How to resolve "RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'" for Tortoise ORM and Celery in FastAPI
I have just started working with Tortoise ORM in FastAPI. This is also the first time I am using an ORM in FastAPI. I have a Celery task that performs some actions and then updates the database using Tortoise ORM.
Below is my code -
updates.py
from tortoise import run_async, Tortoise


async def run_update_bucket_status(bucket_id, size):
    await Tortoise.init(config=TORTOISE_DB_CONFIG)
    source_bucket = await SourceBucket.get(id=bucket_id)
    source_bucket.status = SourceBucket.BucketStatus.ACTIVE
    source_bucket.size = source_bucket.size + size
    await source_bucket.save()


def update_bucket_status(bucket_id, size):
    run_async(run_update_bucket_status(bucket_id=bucket_id, size=size))


async def run_add_sample_faq_to_user_profile(user_profile_id, contents):
    await Tortoise.init(config=TORTOISE_DB_CONFIG)
    user_profile = await UserProfile.get(id=user_profile_id)

    user_history = await generate_user_history(app_id=user_profile.app_id, contents=contents)
    if user_history:
        user_profile.user_history = user_history
        await user_profile.save()


def add_user_history_to_user_profile(user_profile_id, contents):
    run_async(run_add_sample_faq_to_user_profile(user_profile_id=user_profile_id, contents=contents))

tasks.py
@celery_app.task
def parse_document(source_buckets: List[dict], user_profile_id: int):
    all_paragraphs = list()
    for bucket in source_buckets:
        source_type = bucket.get('source_type')
        parser = get_parser(bucket_source=source_type)
        parser = parser()
        paragraphs = parser.get_paragraphs(source=bucket.get('source'))
        total_size = 0
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            size = len(paragraph.encode('utf-8'))
            total_size += size
        
        update_bucket_status(bucket_id=bucket.get('id'), size=total_size)
        all_paragraphs += paragraphs

    add_user_history_to_user_profile(user_profile_id=user_profile_id, contents=all_paragraphs)

When I run the Celery task, update_bucket_status works perfectly. However, add_user_history_to_user_profile raises RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread, even though both are doing almost the same thing. The only difference is that, add_user_history_to_user_profile calls a method, generate_user_history. I should mention, generate_user_history executes some code that connects to the same Postgres database as the Tortoise ORM using the psycopg2 library directly, but connects to tables that are not handled by the Tortoise ORM. I am not sure, but could that be the reason I am encountering this error?
I have tried writing add_user_history_to_user_profile as follows -
def add_user_history_to_user_profile(user_profile_id, contents):
    asyncio.run(run_add_sample_faq_to_user_profile(user_profile_id=user_profile_id, contents=contents))

But this raises the following exception -

objc[56653]: +[NSCharacterSet initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[56653]: +[NSCharacterSet initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
[2024-07-08 18:45:33,318: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-8' pid:56653 exited with 'signal 6 (SIGABRT)'
[2024-07-08 18:45:33,333: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 0.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Neha/Documents/Projects/FastAPI Celery Tortoise ORM/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1264, in mark_as_worker_lost
raise WorkerLostError(
billiard.einfo.ExceptionWithTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Neha/Documents/Projects/FastAPI Celery Tortoise ORM/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1264, in mark_as_worker_lost
raise WorkerLostError(
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 6 (SIGABRT) Job: 0.
"""

I would really appreciate someone helping me figure this out.
